# Can a creature shift while swimming?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement, shift, move-action

The party I was DMing for was fighting in a sewer passage with small water ways running through the passage, and some questions came up about movement and water.  The DM's guide 1 explains some aspects of swimming but it's not very lengthy.

When a creature is swimming can that creature shift?

Is there any keywords or types of movement that allow shifting while swimming?

Answer (score 17):

Per the rules compendium page 249, you can't shift over any terrain that requires a skill check. So unless you have a swim speed, you can't shift while in water.

Here's the excerpt from the Rules Compendium - see the *Special Movement Modes* section:

> #### Shift
>
> **Action:** Move action.
>
> **Movement:** The creature moves 1 square. (Some powers and effects allow creatures to move farther than 1 square with a shift.)
>
> **No Opportunity Actions Triggered:** Unless the description of an effect says otherwise, shifting doesn't trigger opportunity actions such as opportunity attacks.
>
> ***Special Movement Modes:** A creature can't shift when using a movement mode that requires it to make a skill check. For instance, if it is climbing, it can't shift if it has to make an Athletics check to climb. (A creature that has a climb speed can shift while climbing.)*

I normally invert this and say that you can shift over any terrain for which you have movement speed.